# Does the save throw DC calculation from the Superior Technique fighting style override the Battle Master fighter's saving throw DC?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, fighter, fighting-style, battle-master

As the title says, I am trying to determine if the saving throw DC calculation from Superior Technique overrides the calculation from Battle Master, thus eliminating the STR or DEX choice.

> You learn one maneuver of your choice from among those available to the Battle Master archetype. If a maneuver you use requires your
> target to make a saving throw to resist the maneuver's effects, the
> saving throw DC equals 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Strength
> modifier. -- Superior Technique: Strength

> Maneuver save DC = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Strength or Dexterity modifier (your choice) -- Battle Master

Comment: Where are you reading the definition of Superior Technique that you give from? It doesn't match what I read in my online version of Tasha's. Indeed, it seems to be specifically customized to use Strength rather than giving the option to pick between the two. Is that off of a character sheet? It may have asked you which you wanted, and changed the text of the ability.

Comment: Yep.  The sheet had a sub-feature choice of STR or DEX that made it seem like I had to stick with a choice, not "you get the better of STR or DEX".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### In both cases, the saving throw DC lets you choose whether to use your Strength or Dexterity modifier

The relevant part of the actual description of the [Superior Technique](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/fighter#SuperiorTechnique) fighting style says (TCoE, p. 41; emphasis mine):

> [...] If a maneuver you use requires your target to make a saving throw to resist the maneuver’s effects, the saving throw DC equals 8 + your proficiency bonus + **your Strength or Dexterity modifier (your choice)**.

This calculation is identical to the relevant part of the [Battle Master fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#BattleMaster)'s [Combat Superiority](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#CombatSuperiority-209) feature (PHB, p. 73; emphasis mine):

> ***Saving Throws.*** Some of your maneuvers require your target to make a saving throw to resist the maneuver’s effects. The saving throw DC is calculated as follows:
>
> **Maneuver save DC** = 8 + your proficiency bonus + **your Strength or Dexterity modifier (your choice)**

As you can see, regardless of how you get access to Battle Master maneuvers, the saving throw DC is calculated the same way; in both cases, you can choose whether to use your Str mod or your Dex mod (at any time).

Certain online character sheets may display these features differently due to technical limitations, but neither feature requires you to make a single permanent choice of which ability modifier to use. Both the Superior Technique fighting style and the Combat Superiority subclass feature let you choose whether to use Str or Dex at any time (though presumably you'd just use whichever modifier is higher for you).